# What is the impact of locality principles on the pipelining techniques?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines

I know what are both locality principles and pipelining techniques. But I can't see any sort of interconnection between the two things.

How can locality principles impact pipelining techniques?

Comment: Perhaps you could spell out the two locality principles. Maybe if you wait for a few more weeks, the connection will be explained in class.

Comment: Check the answer in SO.